# how the execution engine of stored procedure works in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know what is stored procedure,how to write it , how to call.But yesterday interviewer asked me this question and I told him all about stored procedure,but he does not satisfied with my answer.Can anyone tell me an answer of this question?

Comment: **ASP.NET** is a **web framework** - it doesn't have stored procedures..... those are part of a **database management system** like SQL Server or MySQL or PostgreSQL or whatever you're using.

Comment: Either your interviewer was clueless or he didn't like you and just wanted you out. Nobody other than Microsoft knows exactly how SQL Server executes T-SQL commands. We know higher-level stuffs, like Execution Plan and Wait Statistics. Anyhow, his question is unclear.